ListViewItem.set_Selected gives null reference C#
private void MethodA(string key)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem Item in sRListView.Items)
    {
        if (Item.Text == Key)
            Item.Selected = true;
    }  
}

I am iterating over listview items and if the item matches, I am setting as selected item.  i am getting null exception while setting the item as selected the null exception doesnt occur all the time just randomly occurs and unable to reproduce this , I get an error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

at
System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.set_Selected(Boolean value) 


This code cannot be compiled. You cannot compare a ListViewItem with a string. Please show the real code that gives you the error but first I suggest to read What is a null reference exception and check if you can find your case there

@Steve the condition checks the items text. Item.Text == key. I tried to replicate but not able to get this null reference exception myself

@Steve "You cannot compare a ListViewItem with a string" - who says Key is a string?

@payal if there is  typo in your question,  you should [edit] it

C# is case sensitive. Key != key!

@OlivierJacot-Descombes i am getting null exception and your comment is irrelevant for it

It is relevant, because you declare a key parameter but then use a Key in the comparison. You must compare item.Text == key instead of Item == Key, otherwise this code won't even compile. If you set a breakpoint on the code line throwing the exception, the you will see what is null. See also Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio.
